# I can't make my microphone work after switching to pipewire

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, pipewire

I have just upgraded from kubuntu 22.04 to 22.10 , wich includes also pipewire as default.
Now the microphone is behaving funny. Sometimes it doesnt pick audio at all, sometimes it stutters like crazy, sounding like if the recording was time-warped. On audacity i firstly managed to record something, then it crashed and didn't even show the right microphone entry anymore. I tried to read the outputs of some commands i found on other threads, and to me everything looks off, but i dont know where to start to fix it.

- `pactl info`

```
Server String: /run/user/1000/pulse/native
Library Protocol Version: 35
Server Protocol Version: 35
Is Local: yes
Client Index: 395
Tile Size: 65472
User Name: alessandro
Host Name: kubuntu22
Server Name: PulseAudio (on PipeWire 0.3.58)
Server Version: 15.0.0
Default Sample Specification: float32le 2ch 48000Hz
Default Channel Map: front-left,front-right
Default Sink: alsa_output.pci-0000_28_00.4.analog-stereo.2
Default Source: alsa_input.pci-0000_28_00.4.analog-stereo.4
Cookie: 40c8:32bd
```

- `inxi -Faz` (just the audio section)

```
Audio:
  Device-1: AMD Ellesmere HDMI Audio [Radeon RX 470/480 / 570/580/590]
    vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 3-2:2 pcie:
    chip-ID: 0c45:6366 class-ID: 0102 gen: 3 speed: 8 GT/s serial: <filter>
    lanes: 16 bus-ID: 26:00.1 chip-ID: 1002:aaf0 class-ID: 0403
  Device-2: AMD Starship/Matisse HD Audio vendor: Micro-Star MSI
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel pcie: gen: 4 speed: 16 GT/s lanes: 16
    bus-ID: 28:00.4 chip-ID: 1022:1487 class-ID: 0403
  Device-3: Microdia Webcam Vitade AF type: USB
    driver: snd-usb-audio,uvcvideo
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.19.0-26-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 16.1 running: no
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.58 running: yes
```

- `pipewire`

```
[E][01658.251921] mod.protocol-native | [module-protocol-:  728 lock_socket()] server 0x55edf0438690: unable to lock lockfile '/run/user/1000/pipewire-0.lock': Resource temporarily unavailable (maybe another daemon is running)
[E][01658.251996] pw.conf      | [          conf.c:  594 load_module()] 0x55edf041d2e0: could not load mandatory module "libpipewire-module-protocol-native": Resource temporarily unavailable
[E][01658.252040] default      | [      pipewire.c:  125 main()] failed to create context: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

- `systemctl --user status pipewire pipewire-session-manager`

```
Warning: The unit file, source configuration file or drop-ins of pipewire-session-manager.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl --user daemon-reload' to reload units.
● pipewire.service - PipeWire Multimedia Service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pipewire.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2022-12-16 17:27:39 CET; 32min ago
TriggeredBy: ● pipewire.socket
   Main PID: 1933 (pipewire)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 38285)
     Memory: 25.2M
        CPU: 2.634s
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/session.slice/pipewire.service
             └─1933 /usr/bin/pipewire

dic 16 17:27:39 kubuntu22 systemd[1925]: Started PipeWire Multimedia Service.
dic 16 17:27:39 kubuntu22 pipewire[1933]: mod.rt: Can't find xdg-portal: (null)
dic 16 17:27:39 kubuntu22 pipewire[1933]: mod.rt: found session bus but no portal

○ pipewire-session-manager.service
     Loaded: error (Reason: Unit pipewire-session-manager.service failed to load properly, please adjust/correct and reload service manager: File exists)
     Active: inactive (dead)
```

Do you have any suggestion?
Thanks